# How can I perform a negative match in Android intent filter?

Tags: java, android, regex, manifest, android-intent

In an Android manifest, how can I use a negative match in the `android:pathPattern`?

I'd like to use a `pathPattern` that matches on all URLs *except* for a specific hostname, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like that's possible--in fact, it seems to be designed *not* to work that way.  I suspect `<intent-filter>` is the wrong tool for whatever you're trying to do.

Even if you could use `android:pathPattern` to specify the hostname (isn't that what `android:host` is for?), it's more of a glob than a regex; according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html), it's deliberately underpowered for security reasons.