# Android App Links with multiple domains launching same activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, applinks

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.LaunchActivity"
    android:autoVerify="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="subdomain1.domain.ext"
            android:path="/path1/subpath1/.*"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="subdomain1.domain.ext"
            android:pathPattern="/path2/subpath2/..*"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.ext"
            android:pathPattern="^..*"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

I want to use Android App Links for 2 domains,

1. subdomain1.domain.ext
2. subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.ext

I have already placed the assetlinks.json file at both

```
subdomain1.domain.ext/.well-known/assetlinks.json

subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.ext/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

But on installing the app using Android Studio, 
i **don't see any hits** to either files in the apache server's ***access logs***.

Please note, i am using the release build variant which using the same keystore file which was used to generate the SHA256 fingerprint in assetlinks.json.

When i test with links such as

```
https://subdomain1.domain.ext/path1/subpath1/

https://subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.ext/path2
```

Only the lower one launches the app, the former one simply opens in browser.
So it seems that the final line of code (second host) is set for app link.

***Qn 1***. How to ***open two paths/links on separate hosts with the same activity***? In my case, how can i make the first link also open the app?

***Qn 2***. I want to **restrict opening some links in the app**, i tried this regex as path pattern, it did not work. I know its a glob, is there someway this can be done?

```
android:pathPattern="^(?!foo|bar)..*$"
```

to exclude link paths that begin with foo and bar but allow others.

i want to open

```
example.com in web browser
example.com/test in web browser
example.com/test/temp in web browser
example.com/{anything else} in the app
```

I read the other stackoverflow posts about this:

- [How can I perform a negative match in Android intent filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843260/how-can-i-perform-a-negative-match-in-android-intent-filter)
- [Exclude few Urls from deeplinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184578/exclude-few-urls-from-deeplinking)

But i dont have any query parameters. My situation is pretty much similar to that described in [Android Deep linking omit certain url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422305/android-deep-linking-omit-certain-url)

***Qn 3***. Is it **mandatory** that for the activity where the intent filter for such app links (web link launching app) is defined contain action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER?

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Looking forward to some help. It seems so foolish of the Android team to not allow exclude paths, should have learnt from Apple's server-side file which uses a simple NOT clause.

In case it helps,
this is the java code in the onCreate() method of LaunchActivity

```
public class LaunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            Uri target = intent.getData();
            if (target != null && target.isHierarchical()) {
                String goal = intent.getDataString();
                List<String> params = target.getPathSegments();
                Log.d(TAG, "app uri : " + goal);
                Log.d(TAG, "app link : " + target.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "path segments : " + params);
                if (target.toString().startsWith(MON_DOM)) {
                    if (searchString(AppLinksUtil.TARGET_URLS, target.toString())) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Open TARGET Link in APP");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Open Excluded Link in Browser");
                        openLinkInChrome(LaunchActivity.this, goal);
                        finish();
                    }
                } else if (target.toString().startsWith(ENQ_DOM)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exclude List : " + AppLinksUtil.ENQ_EXCLUDE_URLS);
                    if (searchString(AppLinksUtil.EXCLUDE_URLS, target.toString())) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Open Excluded Link in Browser");
                        openLinkInChrome(LaunchActivity.this, goal);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Open Link in APP");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "no intent");
        }
        appFlow();
    }
    ...
    public void openLinkInChrome(final Activity activity, String link) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Opening " + link + " in web browser");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        try {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            intent.setPackage(null);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    public static boolean searchString(String[] arr, String targetValue) {
        for (String s : arr) {
            if (targetValue.startsWith(s))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On trying some code changes i realized that

**For 1**, There is NO wildcard option for subdomains of same domain, multiple domains are supported, listing them one after the other with correct pathPatterns fixed the problems i was facing.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="subdomain1.example1.com" />
    <data android:host="subdomain2.example1.com" />
    <data android:host="subdomain3.example2.com" />
    <data android:path="/onlythis" />
    <data android:pathPrefix="/starter" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/prefix.*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/.*suffix" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**For 2**, Exclusion of Paths is not possible yet, Google must learn from Apple.

**For 3**, any activity can be linked, not just the MAIN/LAUNCHER one.

action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER is not required for app linking code,
action=VIEW along with category=DEFAULT and BROWSABLE are required and sufficient.

Therefore, different domains/subdomains can launch different activities as long as default and browsable are defined along with action=VIEW

Answer (score 2):

`pathPattern` does not support the full regular expression features. It only supports "*" and ".*". That's it.

See the description of `pathPattern` in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

> The `pathPattern` attribute specifies a complete path that is matched
>   against the complete path in the `Intent` object, but it can contain the
>   following wildcards:
>
> - An asterisk ('*') matches a sequence of 0 to many occurrences of the immediately preceding character.
> - A period followed by an asterisk (".*") matches any sequence of 0 to many characters.

See also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html#PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB

---

You can have as many `<intent-filter>`s as you want for a given `<activity>`. Since you can't use regular expressions to describe the different URLs you want, just create a separate `<intent-filter>` description for each URL.

Comment: how about "+" instead of "*"? i read somewhere that, we should use "..*" in place of ".+", is that true?